# Better table code and coloring table

Tags: tables, color

First thing, I got a table, which looks fine in PDF, but sort of "ugly" in code, and I would like to present as below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1.55in, right=1.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{NET ENTITLEMENT FISH OIL MARKETS}}\\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{AS OF DECEMBER 31, 2019}}\\\hline
    %\rowcolor{Cyan}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Country}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Company}}&Proved Cooked&Proved Uncooked&Total Proved\\
    %\rowcolor{Cyan}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&(T)&(T)&\cellcolor{blue!25}(T)\\\hline
    ChUAN&  &51,574&31,202&82,776\\\hline
    IraW-West POINT &  & 9,656 &57,981&67,637\\\hline
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{KAZSLSKDE}}& PKKR& 32,129 &5,174& 37,304 \\\cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&KOLKOL&9,718&3,447&13,165\\\cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&PKPK&424&0&424\\\hline
     TOTAL CNNNO & & 103,501 & 97,804 & 201,306\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way could improve this ugly code, for example I don't want any `{c|c|c|c|c}` in the codes.

Secondly, I'm confused how to coloring the table, for the two rows to be specifically. I tried and the the second row color would block first row's text.
Is there any way could prevent this.

[image]

Appreciated your kind help.

Regards,

Comment: `{c|c|c|c|c}` can be reduced to `{*{4}{c|}c}`, but it's not shorter, actually.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the second row color blocking the first row text.  Do you mean the `Total Proved` text is covered?

Comment: You could definitely omit all `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` directives.

Comment: @James, when you try to color row 2, which is the (T) row, the blue(or purple) color bar would block bottom of "Country" and "Company". BTW, I need the table to be look exactly as I created, but with different code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by "ugly code", but you could certainly start by getting rid of all `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` directives: they do absolutely nothing -- except create code clutter.

Your table currently has a moderately gaudy look. Assuming that's not intentional, you may want to tone down the impression a bit, e.g., by using a simple, normal-looking caption instead of the two-line bold-face hit-me-smack-between-the-eyes thing. You may also want to strive for a more open look, say, by getting rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules, and using the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining ones. Finally, to help your readers take in (and hopefully comprehend) the numbers you're showing, you may want to choose a somewhat more sophisticated column type than `c`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, vmargin=0.5in, hmargin=1.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Net entitlement fish oil markets as of 31 December  2019} \label{tab:multicol}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll *{3}{S[table-format=6.0]} @{}}
\toprule
Country&Company&{Proved Cooked}&{Proved Uncooked}&{Total Proved}\\
     & &{(T)}&{(T)}&{\color{blue!85}(T)}\\
     \midrule
     ChUAN&  &51574&31202&82776\\
     IraW-West POINT &  & 9656 &57981&67637\\
     KAZSLSKDE& PKKR& 32129 &5174& 37304 \\
     &KOLKOL&9718&3447&13165\\
     &PKPK&424&0&424\\
     TOTAL CNNNO & & 103501 & 97804 & 201306\\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it wasn't for you, i would have posted an answer with decimal commas/points. I decided to add a bit of spacing between the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

My table would be pretty similar, only difference really is the spacing. Micos advice are very good, i cannot add anything to it.

[image: chengzhangTabularDesign]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1.55in, right=1.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Net entitlement fish oil markets as of december 31, 2019}
    \begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
        }
        \toprule
        Country         & Company & {Proved Cooked} & {Proved Uncooked} & {Total Proved}  \\
                        &         & {(T)}           & {(T)}             & {(T)}\\
        \midrule
        ChUAN           &         & 51574           & 31202             & 82776\\\addlinespace
        IraW-West POINT &         & 9656            & 57981             & 67637\\\addlinespace
                        & PKKR    & 32129           & 5174              & 37304 \\
        KAZSLSKDE       & KOLKOL  & 9718            & 3447              & 13165\\
                        & PKPK    & 424             & 0                 & 424\\\addlinespace
        TOTAL CNNNO     &         & 103501          & 97804             & 201306\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```